# Upper bound for embedding of submodules of projective modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Assume we have a finite dimensional algebra $A$ with the following property:

> Every indecomposable submodule of a projective module embedds into $A^n$ for a fixed $n$.

Is there a good method to obtain what the smallest possible $n$ is for the given $A$ or at least obtain a good upper bound (good here means that it is in terms of easily calculated invariants of $A$, for example $2dim(A)+1000$)

An application would be a finite test to check whether an algebra has only finitely many indecomposable submodules of projective modules (such algebras are called torsionless-finite).